Vanishing differential of Brown-Gersten-Quillen spectral sequence
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero and $X$ be an affine, simplicial toric 3-fold over the field $k$. I am trying to use the Brown-Gersten-Quillen spectral sequence to compute the Grothendieck group of coherent sheaves of $X$, $G_0(X)$.
I managed to show that the differentials coming into and leaving the diagonal terms $E_2^{0,0}$ and $E_2^{1,-1}$ on the $E_2$ page all vanish. Hence,$E_{\infty}^{0,0}\cong E_2^{0,0}\cong A^0(X)$ and $E_{\infty}^{1,-1}\cong E_2^{1,-1}\cong A^1(X)$.
Now I am stuck on computing the terms $E_{\infty}^{2,-2}$ and $E_{\infty}^{3,-3}$.
I guess that at least the differential $d_2:E_2^{0,-1}\rightarrow E_2^{2,-2}$ vanishes.
But I am not sure, since $E_2^{0,-1}$ may not be zero.
